# Problems in OS X with Transmit “Mount to Disk” after Mac upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: macos, ftp

I got a problem in Transmit, after upgrading my Mac to El Capitan (v 10.11). When I tray to "Mount to Disk", I get the following Error:

> Internal error (rc=1) while attempting to mount the file system. For now, the best way to diagnose is to look for error messages using Console.

Anyone got a Fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was/is a known issue on transmit 4.4.8 and lower.

Go [get version 4.4.9](https://download.panic.com/transmit/Transmit%20Disk%204.4.9.pkg) or later to work around the known issues.

The developer support page here should be updated and the second link is the announcement of the delay:

- https://library.panic.com/general/mac/el-capitan/
- https://twitter.com/panic/status/648970332473192448

> Quick El Cap Status: Coda mostly works (2.5.12 will bring fixes) — Transmit works — Transmit Disk doesn't work, but we're working on it.
>
> — Panic Inc (@panic) [September 29, 2015](https://twitter.com/panic/status/648970332473192448)

You can check for updates or get on the developer's email list / watch their blog and twitter account for when they have released a version of Transmit Disk that works with El Capitan. The rest of the normal functionality seems to work for me, just the disk mounting part is needing work.

Comment: Fix is now available: "The Transmit Disk feature needs an update to work with OS X El Capitan. You can download Transmit Disk 4.4.9 here."

Comment: https://download.panic.com/transmit/Transmit%20Disk%204.4.9.pkg

Comment: I'm having this problem in OS X 10.11.6 with Transmit 4.4.10. Console says ERROR: invalid signature for com.panic.TransmitDisk.transmitdiskfs, will not load. Uninstalling and reinstalling didn't help.

Comment: Try Mountain Duck (https://mountainduck.io/) which requires no installation of kernel extensions or FUSE libraries.